# Crashlytics - can they see my code if I use Fabric's plugin

Tags: android, security, crashlytics

I use crashlytics to debug android apps and that is why I have Fabric's plugin installed. Can people in Fabric see my project's Android source code ?

Comment: No they just create a crash report from the exception thrown by your code on crash logs console.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric and Crashlytics here.

As Danial mentioned, we don't have access to your application's source code or upload it to our servers. Only a mapping file would be uploaded if you use ProGuard or DexGuard.